# Change owner of everything inside a directory

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo, cookbook

I am using teh following directory chef resource to change ownership of all files within `/etc/temp.d` directory.

```
[ /etc/temp.d ].each do |path|
    directory path do
      recursive true
      owner user1
      group user1
      mode '0750'
      action :create
    end
end
```

However, I see that it changes ownership of only `temp.d` directory to `user1`
The ownership of files and directories inside `temp.d` are not getting changed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `recursive` does not work as you might think there. It only applies the permissions to the leaf directory.

This *is* documented in the [docs](https://docs.chef.io/resource_directory.html), BUT I do understand your confusion... I've been there myself...

> recursive
>
> Ruby Types: TrueClass, FalseClass
>
> Create or delete parent directories recursively. For the owner, group,
>   and mode properties, the value of this attribute applies only to the
>   leaf directory. Default value: false.

You will need to add each (sub)directory to the array you're iterating through, to ensure permissions are applied correctly.

Comment: To explain a bit further, `recursive` means either `mkdir -p` or `rm -r` depending on the action.

Comment: can we add something like `:applies_to_children` in the options section?